# MySQL Sum of Values In a Single Column For Every 50 Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a very simple query like this for my `event_prizes` table:

```
SELECT id, prize FROM event_prizes WHERE event_prizes.event_id = x;
```

Instead of getting the individual price amounts, I need to show the **total amount of the given prize for every 50 rows** in this query. How can I use the SUM function to calculate the total value of every 50 rows?

Comment: your dbms name please

Comment: Oh sure, using MySQL.

Comment: which db ypu are really using ???

Comment: *I need to show the total amount of the given prize for every 50 rows in this query.* Without definite sorting (by the expression which provides rows uniqueness) this makes no sense.

Comment: It doesn't have to make sense, a dummy customer might have asked me to do this. This is not an opinion sharing platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have a colum  with the row number (this id db depending )
You could try grouping by the floor(your_row_num/50)

```
    SELECT floor(your_row_num/50), sum(prize )
    FROM event_prizes WHERE event_prizes.event_id = x
    GROUP BY floor(your_row_num/50);
```

if you have a mysql version 8 you could use ROW_NUMBER  otherwise
use a var and increment